# Can't cleanly break out of the for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Got this simple example:

```
const arr = [
  {name: 'first', amount: 2},
  {name: 'second', amount: 1},
  {name: 'third', amount: 1}
]
const obj = {name: 'second', amount: 3}

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].name === obj.name) {
    arr[i].amount += obj.amount;
    break;
  } else {
    arr.push(obj)
  }
}
```

I want to execute the ordinary for loop and the desired result is that if there's an object with the same name as in the array, then just add up the `amount`, else I want `obj` to be pushed to the list.
But in fact both events happen. How to make so when I break out from if statement the else statement won't run?

Comment: please don't hammer me down. Im new to javascript

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @brk
The desired result is for the second object's amount in the array to be increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another variable `found` and set it to `true`, if the data set is found. Then do not push the actual data set to the array.

Basically you neet to visit all elements and at the end decide if you add the object to the array.

With your code, you take at least one action, either update the actual data set end exit, which works only if the wanted `name` is in the first element, or you push an object to the array. This takes place until the wanted data set is found, or no more elements are available.

```js
const arr = [{ name: 'first', amount: 2 }, { name: 'second', amount: 1 }, { name: 'third', amount: 1 }];
const obj = { name: 'second', amount: 3 };

var found = false;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].name === obj.name) {
        arr[i].amount += obj.amount;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) {
    arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that worked! thank you. But in that case break is not needed

Comment: it is needed, because the loop is still going on.

Answer (score 0):

An arguably more readable way to solve this is using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as follows:

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'first', amount: 2},
  {name: 'second', amount: 1},
  {name: 'third', amount: 1}
];
const obj = {name: 'second', amount: 3};

const element = arr.find(el => el.name === obj.name);

if (element) {
  element.amount += obj.amount;
} else {
  arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `findIndex` and check if there exist an object where name is same as that of object. `findIndex` return `-1` is no result is found. In that case push the `obj` in the array , else update the amount value

```js
const arr = [{
    name: 'first',
    amount: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    amount: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'third',
    amount: 1
  }
]
const obj = {
  name: 'second',
  amount: 3
}


let ifKeyExist = arr.findIndex((item) => {
  return item.name === obj.name
})

if (ifKeyExist === -1) {
  arr.push(obj)
} else {
  arr[ifKeyExist].amount += obj.amount
}
console.log(arr)
```